# Numpy matrix modified through a copy

Tags: python, numpy

In python 2.7.1 with numpy 1.5.1:

```
import numpy as np

B = np.matrix([[-float('inf'), 0], [0., 1]])
print B
Bm = B[1:, :]
Bm[:, 1] = float('inf')
print B
```

returns

```
[[-inf   0.]
 [  0.   1.]]
[[-inf   0.]
 [  0.  inf]]
```

which is quite unexpected because I thought Bm was a copy (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869095/concatenate-numpy-arrays-without-copying)).

Any help figuring this out will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that `-float('inf')` is more directly `float('-inf')`, which has the benefit of not requiring a calculation (taking the opposite of a number).

Comment: Also note that the point in `0.` in the matrix creation is not needed either: the presence of `float('inf')` guarantees that the matrix will be at least of floating type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Basic slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing) in numpy returns a view, as opposed to slicing Python lists, which copies them.

However, slicing will *always* copy data if using advanced slicing, just like concatenating or appending numpy arrays.

Compare

```
a = np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))
a_view = a[::2, ::3]  # basic slicing
a_copy = a[[0, 2], :]  # advanced
```

Answer (score 2):

In my question, it was `np.append` that was making the copy. Slicing will not copy the array/matrix.

You can make `Bm` a copy with

```
Bm = B[1:, :].copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting as from jorgeca's example:

```
a = np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))
a_view = a[::2, ::3]  # basic slicing
a_copy = a[[0, 2], :]  # advanced
```

My additional comment might be off-topic, but it is surprising that both of the following

```
a[::2, ::3]+= 1  # basic slicing
a[[0, 2], :]+= 1 # advanced
```

would make changes on a.