# Number of unique values in columns in two pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I have two `pd.DataFrame` objects (read from .csv file), say,

```
1, 2
1, 3
2, 4
```

and

```
2, 1
1, 2
3, 3
```

Suppose the `DataFrame`'s are named as `data1` and `data2`. So I can easily count the number of unique values in each column of `data1` and `data2` individually using

```
 uniques = data.apply(pd.Series.nunique)
```

`data` is replaced by `data1` and `data2` respectively. So I will get `2, 3` for `data1` and `3, 3` for `data2`. Is there a way (other than concatenating the `DataFrame`'s) so that I can get the number of unique values when these two `DataFrame`'s are combined? I want to get `3, 4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#use numpy unique to count uninues after combining same columns from both DF.

len(np.unique(np.c_[df1.iloc[:,0],df2.iloc[:,0]]))
Out[1398]: 3

len(np.unique(np.c_[df1.iloc[:,1],df2.iloc[:,1]]))
Out[1399]: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I think not. Need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) first:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).apply(pd.Series.nunique)
print (df)
a    3
b    4
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative that will work for any number of data frames:

```
dfs = [df1, df2]
print([
    len(set(np.concatenate([df[colname].unique() for df in dfs])))
    for colname in dfs[0]
])
[3, 4]
```

Note that this will only work if all the data frames have the same column names.

I think that `concat` is the best option, unless your data frames already fill your local memory: [concatenating will copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869095/concatenate-numpy-arrays-without-copying/7869472#7869472)

Comment: I wanted to avoid the concatenation. It's vanilla!