# How to concatenate two pandas dataframes after replacing data within one function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a function which takes a dataframe, duplicates it, changes the values in one of the columns and then concatenates them together. For example:

df1 looks like

```
column1 | column2 | column3
keyword1|    1    |   20
keyword2|    1    |   40
keyword3|    1    |   60
```

and I want a function which creates this:

```
column1 | column2 | column3
keyword1|    1    |   20
keyword2|    1    |   40
keyword3|    1    |   60
keyword1|    2    |   20
keyword2|    2    |   40
keyword3|    2    |   60
```

I've tried this:

```
def add_mobile(df):

    mobiledf = df.copy(deep=True)
    mobiledf['column2'].replace(1,2,inplace=True)

    df = pd.concat([df,mobiledf],axis=0)
```

however when I put df1 though this function it returns df1 unedited. If I then look at `df1.shape` it has not changed.

Comment: Can you try return df below the function? Because I have tried your code and it worked for me.

Comment: The second function just returns the copied and modified `df`. Do you assign it to variable and perform the concat afterwards?

Comment: The second function is there to show that the second DF is being made with no problems. The first function does concatenate them.

Comment: You are not returning your df in first function and the second function does not concat the dataframes.

Comment: If I put a return statement in my function it works, however when I add df1 as a parameter  it doesn't actually edit df1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First function**

You didn't return df so it didn't do anything:

```
def add_mobile(df):

    mobiledf = df.copy(deep=True)
    mobiledf['column2'].replace(1,2,inplace=True)

    df = pd.concat([df,mobiledf],axis=0)

    return df
```

**Second function:**

You didn't concatenate:

```
def add_mobile(df):

    mobiledf = df.copy(deep=True)
    mobiledf['column2'].replace(1,2,inplace=True)

    return pd.concat([df,mobiledf],axis=0)
```

**Concatenate is not an in-place function**

Finlay, concatenate is not an in-place function, so you should always retrieve the result:

```
df = add_mobile(df)
```

Comment: This function works. But when I look at `df1.shape` it remains the same and does not have the other df concatenated. It's as if there's an `inplace=True` missing or something

Comment: Yes, this is because concat is not an inplace function. Just perform `df1 = add_mobile(df1)`

Comment: Are have a look at this [question about concatenating without copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869095/concatenate-numpy-arrays-without-copying)

Answer (score 1):

[image]This worked for me:

```
def add_mobile(df):
   mobiledf = df.copy(deep=True)
   mobiledf['column2'].replace(1,2,inplace=True)
   df = pd.concat([df,mobiledf],axis=0,ignore_index=True)
   return df
```